# Runnable + Diferencia de Fechas + Persona Empezando con Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Estoy actualmente empezando con un curso de Android, y después de aprender a manejar los XML, estoy empezando con Java. Pues bien, siempre uno trata de alcanzar más de lo que puede abarcar y disfrutar haciendo alguna aplicación para divertirse antes de verlo en el curso, mi problema seguramente sea de 1º de Android, pero ahi vá.

Quiero obtener la diferencia entre dos fechas y que se muestre en pantalla hasta la diferencia que hay en segundos. Ok, eso conseguido con una clase `public void ObtenerFecha()`; pero ahora quiero ir un paso más allá y que la diferencia de fechas se actualice constantemente, y que cada segundo que transcurra se vea aumentado en pantalla esta diferencia. Pues me he puesto con el `Runnable` pero no logro que me muestre el texto en el `TexView`.

Pego el código de la discordia:

```
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import android.os.Handler;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    String fechaInicio = "15-01-2017 11:30:00";

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            class ObtenerFecha {
                public void main(String[] args) {

                    try {
                        //Fecha de Inicio
                        SimpleDateFormat stringDate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                        Date DateInicio = stringDate1.parse(fechaInicio);
                        Calendar CalendarInicio = new GregorianCalendar();
                        CalendarInicio.setTime(DateInicio);

                        //Obtener fecha actual
                        Calendar CalendarActual = new GregorianCalendar();
                        Date DateActual = CalendarActual.getTime();
                        SimpleDateFormat stringDate2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                        String fechaActual = stringDate2.format(DateActual);

                        // tomamos la instancia del tipo de calendario

                        Calendar stringCalendarActual = Calendar.getInstance();


                        // obtenemos el valor de las fechas en milisegundos
                        long milisegundos1 = CalendarInicio.getTimeInMillis();
                        long milisegundos2 = CalendarActual.getTimeInMillis();
                        // tomamos la diferencia
                        long diffMilisegundos = milisegundos2 - milisegundos1;


                        // calcular la diferencia en segundos
                        long diffSegundos = Math.abs(diffMilisegundos / 1000);
                        long diferenciasegundos = diffMilisegundos % 60;

                        // calcular la diferencia en minutos
                        long diffMinutos = Math.abs(diffMilisegundos / (60 * 1000));
                        long restominutos = diffMinutos % 60;

                        // calcular la diferencia en horas
                        long diffHoras = (diffMilisegundos / (60 * 60 * 1000));
                        long restohoras = diffHoras % 24;

                        // calcular la diferencia en dias
                        long diffdias = Math.abs(diffMilisegundos / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

                        String diferencia = diffdias + " días \n" + restohoras + " horas \n" + restominutos + " minutos y \n" + diferenciasegundos + " segundos";

                        //Llamada para mostrar fechas
                        mostrarDiferencia(diferencia);

                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        //Log.e(TAG, “Función obtenerFecha: Error Parse “ e);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        //Log.e(TAG, “Función obtenerFecha: Error “ + e);
                    }

                }

            }

            Log.d("Handlers", "Called on main thread");

            // Run the above code block on the main thread after 2 seconds
            handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, 2000);
        }
    };



    private void mostrarDiferencia(String message) {
        TextView priceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.diferencia);
        priceTextView.setText(message);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hiciste una depuración? Te salió una excepción?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu codigo no se ejecuta debido a que en Android Java se comporta un poco distinto el ciclo de vida de la Activity comienza en el onCreate por lo tanto el metodo main no se ejecutara y tu codigo debe verse similar a esto :

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.net.ParseException;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

    import android.os.Handler;
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    runnableCode.run();

}

String fechaInicio = "15-01-2017 11:30:00";

Handler handler = new Handler();


private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            //Fecha de Inicio
            SimpleDateFormat stringDate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            Date DateInicio = stringDate1.parse(fechaInicio);
            Calendar CalendarInicio = new GregorianCalendar();
            CalendarInicio.setTime(DateInicio);

            //Obtener fecha actual
            Calendar CalendarActual = new GregorianCalendar();
            Date DateActual = CalendarActual.getTime();
            SimpleDateFormat stringDate2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            String fechaActual = stringDate2.format(DateActual);

            // tomamos la instancia del tipo de calendario

            Calendar stringCalendarActual = Calendar.getInstance();


            // obtenemos el valor de las fechas en milisegundos
            long milisegundos1 = CalendarInicio.getTimeInMillis();
            long milisegundos2 = CalendarActual.getTimeInMillis();
            // tomamos la diferencia
            long diffMilisegundos = milisegundos2 - milisegundos1;


            // calcular la diferencia en segundos
            long diffSegundos = Math.abs(diffMilisegundos / 1000);
            long diferenciasegundos = diffMilisegundos % 60;

            // calcular la diferencia en minutos
            long diffMinutos = Math.abs(diffMilisegundos / (60 * 1000));
            long restominutos = diffMinutos % 60;

            // calcular la diferencia en horas
            long diffHoras = (diffMilisegundos / (60 * 60 * 1000));
            long restohoras = diffHoras % 24;

            // calcular la diferencia en dias
            long diffdias = Math.abs(diffMilisegundos / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

            String diferencia = diffdias + " días \n" + restohoras + " horas \n" + restominutos + " minutos y \n" + diferenciasegundos + " segundos";

            //Llamada para mostrar fechas
            mostrarDiferencia(diferencia);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            //Log.e(TAG, “Función obtenerFecha: Error Parse “ e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.e(TAG, “Función obtenerFecha: Error “ + e);
        }

        /*
        class ObtenerFecha {
            public void main(String[] args) {

                try {
                    //Fecha de Inicio
                    SimpleDateFormat stringDate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                    Date DateInicio = stringDate1.parse(fechaInicio);
                    Calendar CalendarInicio = new GregorianCalendar();
                    CalendarInicio.setTime(DateInicio);

                    //Obtener fecha actual
                    Calendar CalendarActual = new GregorianCalendar();
                    Date DateActual = CalendarActual.getTime();
                    SimpleDateFormat stringDate2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                    String fechaActual = stringDate2.format(DateActual);

                    // tomamos la instancia del tipo de calendario

                    Calendar stringCalendarActual = Calendar.getInstance();


                    // obtenemos el valor de las fechas en milisegundos
                    long milisegundos1 = CalendarInicio.getTimeInMillis();
                    long milisegundos2 = CalendarActual.getTimeInMillis();
                    // tomamos la diferencia
                    long diffMilisegundos = milisegundos2 - milisegundos1;


                    // calcular la diferencia en segundos
                    long diffSegundos = Math.abs(diffMilisegundos / 1000);
                    long diferenciasegundos = diffMilisegundos % 60;

                    // calcular la diferencia en minutos
                    long diffMinutos = Math.abs(diffMilisegundos / (60 * 1000));
                    long restominutos = diffMinutos % 60;

                    // calcular la diferencia en horas
                    long diffHoras = (diffMilisegundos / (60 * 60 * 1000));
                    long restohoras = diffHoras % 24;

                    // calcular la diferencia en dias
                    long diffdias = Math.abs(diffMilisegundos / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

                    String diferencia = diffdias + " días \n" + restohoras + " horas \n" + restominutos + " minutos y \n" + diferenciasegundos + " segundos";

                    //Llamada para mostrar fechas
                    mostrarDiferencia(diferencia);

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    //Log.e(TAG, “Función obtenerFecha: Error Parse “ e);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //Log.e(TAG, “Función obtenerFecha: Error “ + e);
                }

            }

        }
        */

        Log.d("Handlers", "Called on main thread");

        // Run the above code block on the main thread after 2 seconds
        handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, 2000);
    }
};



private void mostrarDiferencia(String message) {
    TextView priceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.diferencia);
    priceTextView.setText(message);
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que haces no funciona ni en `Android` ni en `Java` corriente. El método `main(String args...)` es solamente un punto de entrada que defines para ejecutar un programa, y aun que puedes implementar `main` en varias clases, para correr un programa normalmente usas un punto de entrada no más.

Cometes los siguientes errores:

- creas un objeto de clase anónima con interfaz `Runnable`, pero nunca la usas después
- creas una clase con un método `main`, pero como método del objeto, no `static`
- defines la clase en el método `run`, y tampoco lo usas.

el método `main(String args...)` no tiene nada mágico. Se define con modificador `static` en clases para poder lanzar programas. Aparte de eso es un método cualquiera, que se podría llamar como `MiClase.main(args)` desde tu código, pero es muy poco común y generalmente no necesario.

Te recomiendo de definir tu acción que quieres ejecutar recorriente (cada 2 segundos) como clase interno y lanzarlo desde `onCreate`en la siguiente manera:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String fechaInicio = "15-01-2017 11:30:00";
    Handler handler;
    Runnable obtenerFecha;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        handler = new Handler();
        obtenerFecha = new ObtenerFecha();
        handler.post(obtenerFecha);
    }


    private void mostrarDiferencia(String message) {
        TextView priceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.diferencia);
        priceTextView.setText(message);
    }

    class ObtenerFecha implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run() {
                    try {
                        //Fecha de Inicio
                        SimpleDateFormat stringDate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                        Date DateInicio = stringDate1.parse(fechaInicio);
                        Calendar CalendarInicio = new GregorianCalendar();
                        CalendarInicio.setTime(DateInicio);

                        //Obtener fecha actual
                        Calendar CalendarActual = new GregorianCalendar();
                        Date DateActual = CalendarActual.getTime();
                        SimpleDateFormat stringDate2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                        String fechaActual = stringDate2.format(DateActual);

                        // tomamos la instancia del tipo de calendario

                        Calendar stringCalendarActual = Calendar.getInstance();


                        // obtenemos el valor de las fechas en milisegundos
                        long milisegundos1 = CalendarInicio.getTimeInMillis();
                        long milisegundos2 = CalendarActual.getTimeInMillis();
                        // tomamos la diferencia
                        long diffMilisegundos = milisegundos2 - milisegundos1;


                        // calcular la diferencia en segundos
                        long diffSegundos = Math.abs(diffMilisegundos / 1000);
                        long diferenciasegundos = diffMilisegundos % 60;

                        // calcular la diferencia en minutos
                        long diffMinutos = Math.abs(diffMilisegundos / (60 * 1000));
                        long restominutos = diffMinutos % 60;

                        // calcular la diferencia en horas
                        long diffHoras = (diffMilisegundos / (60 * 60 * 1000));
                        long restohoras = diffHoras % 24;

                        // calcular la diferencia en dias
                        long diffdias = Math.abs(diffMilisegundos / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

                        String diferencia = diffdias + " días \n" + restohoras + " horas \n" + restominutos + " minutos y \n" + diferenciasegundos + " segundos";

                        //Llamada para mostrar fechas
                        mostrarDiferencia(diferencia);

                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        //Log.e(TAG, “Función obtenerFecha: Error Parse “ e);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        //Log.e(TAG, “Función obtenerFecha: Error “ + e);
                    }
            Log.d("Handlers", "Called on main thread");

            // Run the above code block on the main thread after 2 seconds
            handler.postDelayed(ObtenerFecha.this, 2000);
        }
    }
}
```

Mejor aun sería de implementar una manera de interrumpir el trabajo para evitar que hay actualisaciones mientras tu app esta en segundo plano, arrancando la ejecución en `onStart` y interumpiendolo en `onStop`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, me funciona perfectamente y muchas más gracias por la explicación porque me has aclarado bastantes lios que tenia en la cabeza con respecto al codigo que estaba haciendo y los has explicado perfectamente.

Me toca seguir estudiando para no tener estos errores.

Comment: Es generalmente considerado buena practica en SO que uno expresa su respeto para una respuesta útil por voto y/o por aceptación, evitando las gracias en comentarios. Así es más fácil para otros de filtrar respuestas por calidad. Yo también lucho un poco con el concepto, porque me nacen las cortesías, pero se entiende el sentido de enfocar lo más que posible en lo informativo, @JuanKar.